# Media Foundation EVR no video displaying

Tags: visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

I've been trying in vain to come up with a no frills example of displaying video using Microsoft's Media Foundation Enhanced Video Renderer (EVR). I'm testing on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2013.

I'm pretty sure I've got the media types configured correctly as I can export and save the buffer from the IMFSample in my read loop to a bitmap. I can also get the video to render IF I get MF to automatically generate the topology but in this case I need to wire up the source reader and sink writer manually so I can get access to the different parts of the pipeline.

I have used mftrace to see if I can spot anything different between the automatically generated topology and the manually wired up example but nothing obvious jumps out.

The code is below (full sample project at https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/tree/master/MFVideoEVR).

Is there a step I've missed to get the IMFSample from the SinkWriter to display on the video window? I've been looking at a few examples that go deeper into the DirectX pipeline but should that be necessary or is the EVR meant to abstract those mechanics aways?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <evr.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include "..\Common\MFUtility.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "evr.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Strmiids")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")

#define CHECK_HR(hr, msg) if (hr != S_OK) { printf(msg); printf("Error: %.2X.\n", hr); goto done; }

void InitializeWindow();

// Constants 
const WCHAR CLASS_NAME[] = L"MFVideoEVR Window Class";
const WCHAR WINDOW_NAME[] = L"MFVideoEVR";

// Globals.
HWND _hwnd;

using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

int main()
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    IMFMediaSource *videoSource = NULL;
    UINT32 videoDeviceCount = 0;
    IMFAttributes *videoConfig = NULL;
    IMFActivate **videoDevices = NULL;
    IMFSourceReader *videoReader = NULL;
    WCHAR *webcamFriendlyName;
    IMFMediaType *videoSourceOutputType = NULL, *pvideoSourceModType = NULL, *pSrcOutMediaType = NULL;
    IMFSourceResolver *pSourceResolver = NULL;
    IUnknown* uSource = NULL;
    IMFMediaSource *mediaFileSource = NULL;
    IMFAttributes *pVideoReaderAttributes = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pVideoOutType = NULL;
    MF_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;
    IMFMediaSink *pVideoSink = NULL;
    IMFStreamSink *pStreamSink = NULL;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler *pMediaTypeHandler = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pSinkMediaType = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFVideoRenderer *pVideoRenderer = NULL;
    IMFVideoPresenter *pVideoPresenter = nullptr;
    IMFVideoDisplayControl *pVideoDisplayControl = nullptr;
    IMFGetService *pService = nullptr;
    IMFActivate* pActive = NULL;
    MFVideoNormalizedRect nrcDest = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    IMFPresentationTimeSource *pSystemTimeSource = nullptr;
    IMFMediaType *sinkPreferredType = nullptr;
    IMFPresentationClock *pClock = NULL;
    IMFPresentationTimeSource *pTimeSource = NULL;

    CHECK_HR(MFTRegisterLocalByCLSID(
        __uuidof(CColorConvertDMO),
        MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_PROCESSOR,
        L"",
        MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL
        ), "Error registering colour converter DSP.\n");

    Task::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Action(InitializeWindow));

    Sleep(1000);

    if (_hwnd == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialise video window.\n");
        goto done;
    }

    // Set up the reader for the file.
    CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceResolver(&pSourceResolver), "MFCreateSourceResolver failed.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromURL(
        L"..\\..\\MediaFiles\\big_buck_bunny.mp4",      // URL of the source.
        MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE,  // Create a source object.
        NULL,                       // Optional property store.
        &ObjectType,                // Receives the created object type. 
        &uSource                    // Receives a pointer to the media source.
        ), "Failed to create media source resolver for file.\n");

    CHECK_HR(uSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mediaFileSource)), "Failed to create media file source.\n");

    CHECK_HR(MFCreateAttributes(&pVideoReaderAttributes, 2), "Failed to create attributes object for video reader.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoReaderAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID), "Failed to set dev source attribute type for reader config.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoReaderAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_VIDEO_PROCESSING, 1), "Failed to set enable video processing attribute type for reader config.\n");

    CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(mediaFileSource, pVideoReaderAttributes, &videoReader),
        "Error creating media source reader.\n");

    CHECK_HR(videoReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &videoSourceOutputType),
        "Error retrieving current media type from first video stream.\n");

    Console::WriteLine("Default output media type for source reader:");
    Console::WriteLine(GetMediaTypeDescription(videoSourceOutputType));
    Console::WriteLine();

    // Set the video output type on the source reader.
    CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&pvideoSourceModType), "Failed to create video output media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set video output media major type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32), "Failed to set video sub-type attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive), "Failed to set interlace mode attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE), "Failed to set independent samples attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pvideoSourceModType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set pixel aspect ratio attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pvideoSourceModType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE), "Failed to copy video frame size attribute from input file to output sink.\n");
    CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pvideoSourceModType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE), "Failed to copy video frame rate attribute from input file to output sink.\n");

    CHECK_HR(videoReader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, NULL, pvideoSourceModType), "Failed to set media type on source reader.\n");

    Console::WriteLine("Output media type set on source reader:");
    Console::WriteLine(GetMediaTypeDescription(pvideoSourceModType));
    Console::WriteLine();

    // Create EVR sink .
    //CHECK_HR(MFCreateVideoRenderer(__uuidof(IMFMediaSink), (void**)&pVideoSink), "Failed to create video sink.\n");

    CHECK_HR(MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(_hwnd, &pActive), "Failed to created video rendered activation context.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pActive->ActivateObject(IID_IMFMediaSink, (void**)&pVideoSink), "Failed to activate IMFMediaSink interface on video sink.\n");

    // Initialize the renderer before doing anything else including querying for other interfaces (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704667(v=vs.85).aspx).
    CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFVideoRenderer), (void**)&pVideoRenderer), "Failed to get video Renderer interface from EVR media sink.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoRenderer->InitializeRenderer(NULL, NULL), "Failed to initialise the video renderer.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFGetService), (void**)&pService), "Failed to get service interface from EVR media sink.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pService->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFVideoDisplayControl), (void**)&pVideoDisplayControl), "Failed to get video display control interface from service interface.\n");

    CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &pStreamSink), "Failed to get video renderer stream by index.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pMediaTypeHandler), "Failed to get media type handler.\n");

    // Set the video output type on the source reader.
    CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&pVideoOutType), "Failed to create video output media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set video output media major type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32), "Failed to set video sub-type attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive), "Failed to set interlace mode attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE), "Failed to set independent samples attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pVideoOutType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set pixel aspect ratio attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE), "Failed to copy video frame size attribute from input file to output sink.\n");
    CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE), "Failed to copy video frame rate attribute from input file to output sink.\n");

    //CHECK_HR(pMediaTypeHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(0, &pSinkMediaType), "Failed to get sink media type.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pMediaTypeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pVideoOutType), "Failed to set current media type.\n");

    Console::WriteLine("Input media type set on EVR:");
    Console::WriteLine(GetMediaTypeDescription(pVideoOutType));
    Console::WriteLine();

    CHECK_HR(MFCreatePresentationClock(&pClock), "Failed to create presentation clock.\n");
    CHECK_HR(MFCreateSystemTimeSource(&pTimeSource), "Failed to create system time source.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pClock->SetTimeSource(pTimeSource), "Failed to set time source.\n");
    //CHECK_HR(pClock->Start(0), "Error starting presentation clock.\n");
    CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->SetPresentationClock(pClock), "Failed to set presentation clock on video sink.\n");

    Console::WriteLine("Press any key to start video sampling...");
    Console::ReadLine();

    IMFSample *videoSample = NULL;
    DWORD streamIndex, flags;
    LONGLONG llTimeStamp;

    while (true)
    {
        CHECK_HR(videoReader->ReadSample(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            0,                              // Flags.
            &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
            &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
            &llTimeStamp,                   // Receives the time stamp.
            &videoSample                    // Receives the sample or NULL.
            ), "Error reading video sample.");

        if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
        {
            printf("End of stream.\n");
            break;
        }
        if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK)
        {
            printf("Stream tick.\n");
        }

        if (!videoSample)
        {
            printf("Null video sample.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Attempting to write sample to stream sink.\n");

            CHECK_HR(videoSample->SetSampleTime(llTimeStamp), "Error setting the video sample time.\n");
            //CHECK_HR(videoSample->SetSampleDuration(41000000), "Error setting the video sample duration.\n");

            CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->ProcessSample(videoSample), "Streamsink process sample failed.\n");
        }

        SafeRelease(&videoSample);
    }

done:

    printf("finished.\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void InitializeWindow()
{
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    if (RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        _hwnd = CreateWindow(
            CLASS_NAME,
            WINDOW_NAME,
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            640,
            480,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL
            );

        if (_hwnd)
        {
            ShowWindow(_hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            MSG msg = { 0 };

            while (true)
            {
                if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Sleep(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is my understanding that Media sinks use a [pull model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#data_flow).  You are expected to send samples in response to [MEStreamSinkRequestSample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it seems that EVR needs [Video Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530110(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The video sample object is a specialized implementation of the IMFSample interface for use with the Enhanced Video Renderer (EVR).

But it seems not to be needed to manually provide Video Samples if the decoder supports DXVA [IMFVideoSampleAllocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473823(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The Media Session uses this interface to allocate samples for the EVR, unless the upstream decoder supports DirectX Video Acceleration (DXVA).

I think you should investigate under IMFVideoSampleAllocator, because your software acts like a mediasession.

You also need to call clock start, just before "while loop video processing".
You also need to release all interfaces, stop clock and call some shutdown method.

Like David Wohlferd said, you should handle Media Sink Events too, for better improvment of your program.

EDIT :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <evr.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include "MFUtility.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#include <d3d9.h>
#include <mfobjects.h>
#include <Dxva2api.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "evr.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Strmiids")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")

#define CHECK_HR(hr, msg) if (hr != S_OK) { printf(msg); printf("Error: %.2X.\n", hr); goto done; }

void InitializeWindow();
HRESULT CreateD3DSample(IDirect3DSwapChain9 *pSwapChain, IMFSample **ppVideoSample);

// Constants 
const WCHAR CLASS_NAME[] = L"MFVideoEVR Window Class";
const WCHAR WINDOW_NAME[] = L"MFVideoEVR";

// Globals.
HWND _hwnd;
LPDIRECT3D9 _d3d;    // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 _d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class
IDirect3DSwapChain9 * _pSwapChain;
IDirect3DTexture9 *_pd3dTexture;

#define VIDEO_WIDTH  320
#define VIDEO_HEIGHT 240

using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

int main()
{
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

IMFMediaSource *videoSource = NULL;
UINT32 videoDeviceCount = 0;
IMFAttributes *videoConfig = NULL;
IMFActivate **videoDevices = NULL;
IMFSourceReader *videoReader = NULL;
WCHAR *webcamFriendlyName;
IMFMediaType *videoSourceOutputType = NULL, *pvideoSourceModType = NULL, *pSrcOutMediaType = NULL;
IMFSourceResolver *pSourceResolver = NULL;
IUnknown* uSource = NULL;
IMFMediaSource *mediaFileSource = NULL;
IMFAttributes *pVideoReaderAttributes = NULL;
IMFMediaType *pVideoOutType = NULL;
MF_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;
IMFMediaSink *pVideoSink = NULL;
IMFStreamSink *pStreamSink = NULL;
IMFMediaTypeHandler *pMediaTypeHandler = NULL;
IMFMediaType *pMediaType = NULL;
IMFMediaType *pSinkMediaType = NULL;
IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;
IMFVideoRenderer *pVideoRenderer = NULL;
IMFVideoPresenter *pVideoPresenter = nullptr;
IMFVideoDisplayControl *pVideoDisplayControl = nullptr;
IMFGetService *pService = nullptr;
IMFActivate* pActive = NULL;
MFVideoNormalizedRect nrcDest = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
IMFPresentationTimeSource *pSystemTimeSource = nullptr;
IMFMediaType *sinkPreferredType = nullptr;
IMFPresentationClock *pClock = NULL;
IMFPresentationTimeSource *pTimeSource = NULL;
IDirect3DDeviceManager9 * pD3DManager = NULL;
IMFVideoSampleAllocator* pEvrSampleAllocator = nullptr;
// Add
IMFVideoSampleAllocator* pVideoSampleAllocator = NULL;
IMFSample* pD3DVideoSample = NULL;
RECT rc = { 0, 0, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT };

CHECK_HR(MFTRegisterLocalByCLSID(
    __uuidof(CColorConvertDMO),
    MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_PROCESSOR,
    L"",
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL
), "Error registering colour converter DSP.\n");

Task::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Action(InitializeWindow));

Sleep(1000);

if (_hwnd == nullptr)
{
    printf("Failed to initialise video window.\n");
    goto done;
}

// Create EVR sink .
//CHECK_HR(MFCreateVideoRenderer(__uuidof(IMFMediaSink), (void**)&pVideoSink), "Failed to create video sink.\n");

CHECK_HR(MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(_hwnd, &pActive), "Failed to created video rendered activation context.\n");
CHECK_HR(pActive->ActivateObject(IID_IMFMediaSink, (void**)&pVideoSink), "Failed to activate IMFMediaSink interface on video sink.\n");

// Initialize the renderer before doing anything else including querying for other interfaces (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704667(v=vs.85).aspx).
CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFVideoRenderer), (void**)&pVideoRenderer), "Failed to get video Renderer interface from EVR media sink.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoRenderer->InitializeRenderer(NULL, NULL), "Failed to initialise the video renderer.\n");

CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFGetService), (void**)&pService), "Failed to get service interface from EVR media sink.\n");
CHECK_HR(pService->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFVideoDisplayControl), (void**)&pVideoDisplayControl), "Failed to get video display control interface from service interface.\n");

CHECK_HR(pVideoDisplayControl->SetVideoWindow(_hwnd), "Failed to SetVideoWindow.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoDisplayControl->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &rc), "Failed to SetVideoPosition.\n");

CHECK_HR(MFGetService(pVideoSink, MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pD3DManager)), "Failed to get Direct3D manager from EVR media sink.\n");

//CHECK_HR(MFGetService(pVideoSink, MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEvrSampleAllocator)), "Failed to get sample allocator from EVR media sink.\n");

//CHECK_HR(pService->GetService(MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFVideoSampleAllocator), (void**)pEvrSampleAllocator), "Failed to get sample allocator from EVR media sink.\n");

// Set up the reader for the file.
CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceResolver(&pSourceResolver), "MFCreateSourceResolver failed.\n");

CHECK_HR(pSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromURL(
    L"big_buck_bunny_240p_5mb.mp4",     // URL of the source.
    MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE,  // Create a source object.
    NULL,                       // Optional property store.
    &ObjectType,                // Receives the created object type. 
    &uSource                    // Receives a pointer to the media source.
), "Failed to create media source resolver for file.\n");

CHECK_HR(uSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mediaFileSource)), "Failed to create media file source.\n");

CHECK_HR(MFCreateAttributes(&pVideoReaderAttributes, 2), "Failed to create attributes object for video reader.\n");
//CHECK_HR(pVideoReaderAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID), "Failed to set dev source attribute type for reader config.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoReaderAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_VIDEO_PROCESSING, 1), "Failed to set enable video processing attribute type for reader config.\n");
//CHECK_HR(pVideoReaderAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_ADVANCED_VIDEO_PROCESSING, 1), "Failed to set enable advanced video processing attribute type for reader config.\n");
//CHECK_HR(pVideoReaderAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER, pD3DManager), "Failed to set D3D manager attribute type for reader config.\n");

CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(mediaFileSource, pVideoReaderAttributes, &videoReader),
    "Error creating media source reader.\n");

CHECK_HR(videoReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &videoSourceOutputType),
    "Error retrieving current media type from first video stream.\n");

Console::WriteLine("Default output media type for source reader:");
Console::WriteLine(GetMediaTypeDescription(videoSourceOutputType));
Console::WriteLine();

// Set the video output type on the source reader.
CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&pvideoSourceModType), "Failed to create video output media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set video output media major type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32), "Failed to set video sub-type attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive), "Failed to set interlace mode attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE), "Failed to set independent samples attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pvideoSourceModType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set pixel aspect ratio attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pvideoSourceModType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE), "Failed to copy video frame size attribute from input file to output sink.\n");
CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pvideoSourceModType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE), "Failed to copy video frame rate attribute from input file to output sink.\n");
//CHECK_HR(pvideoSourceModType->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER, pD3DManager), "Failed to set D3D manager attribute type on EVR input media type.\n");

CHECK_HR(videoReader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, NULL, pvideoSourceModType), "Failed to set media type on source reader.\n");

Console::WriteLine("Output media type set on source reader:");
Console::WriteLine(GetMediaTypeDescription(pvideoSourceModType));
Console::WriteLine();

CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &pStreamSink), "Failed to get video renderer stream by index.\n");
CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pMediaTypeHandler), "Failed to get media type handler.\n");

// Set the video output type on the source reader.
CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&pVideoOutType), "Failed to create video output media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set video output media major type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32), "Failed to set video sub-type attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive), "Failed to set interlace mode attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE), "Failed to set independent samples attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pVideoOutType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set pixel aspect ratio attribute on EVR input media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE), "Failed to copy video frame size attribute from input file to output sink.\n");
CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE), "Failed to copy video frame rate attribute from input file to output sink.\n");
//CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER, pD3DManager), "Failed to set D3D manager attribute on EVR input media type.\n");

//CHECK_HR(pMediaTypeHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(0, &pSinkMediaType), "Failed to get sink media type.\n");
CHECK_HR(pMediaTypeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pVideoOutType), "Failed to set current media type.\n");

Console::WriteLine("Input media type set on EVR:");
Console::WriteLine(GetMediaTypeDescription(pVideoOutType));
Console::WriteLine();

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa473823(v=vs.85).aspx
CHECK_HR(MFGetService(pStreamSink, MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pVideoSampleAllocator)), "Failed to get IMFVideoSampleAllocator.\n");
CHECK_HR(MFGetService(pVideoSink, MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pD3DManager)), "Failed to get D3DManager.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoSampleAllocator->SetDirectXManager(pD3DManager), "Failed to set D3DManager.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoSampleAllocator->InitializeSampleAllocator(1, pVideoOutType), "Failed to InitializeSampleAllocator.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoSampleAllocator->AllocateSample(&pD3DVideoSample), "Failed to AllocateSample.\n");

CHECK_HR(MFCreatePresentationClock(&pClock), "Failed to create presentation clock.\n");
CHECK_HR(MFCreateSystemTimeSource(&pTimeSource), "Failed to create system time source.\n");
CHECK_HR(pClock->SetTimeSource(pTimeSource), "Failed to set time source.\n");
CHECK_HR(pVideoSink->SetPresentationClock(pClock), "Failed to set presentation clock on video sink.\n");
CHECK_HR(pClock->Start(0), "Error starting presentation clock.\n");

// Wait for the Sink to start
Sleep(1000);

//_d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);    // create the Direct3D interface

//D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;    // create a struct to hold various device information

//ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));    // clear out the struct for use
//d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;    // program windowed, not fullscreen
//d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;    // discard old frames
//d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = _hwnd;    // set the window to be used by Direct3D
//d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;    // set the back buffer format to 32-bit
//d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 640;    // set the width of the buffer
//d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 360;    // set the height of the buffer

//// create a device class using this information and information from the d3dpp stuct
//_d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
//  D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
//  _hwnd,
//  D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
//  &d3dpp,
//  &_d3ddev);

//CHECK_HR(_d3ddev->GetSwapChain(0, &_pSwapChain), "Failed to get swap chain from D3D device.\n");

////_d3ddev->CreateTexture(640, 360, 0, 0, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &_pd3dTexture, NULL);

//// clear the window to a deep blue
//_d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);
//_d3ddev->BeginScene();    // begins the 3D scene

//_d3ddev->EndScene();    // ends the 3D scene
//_d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);    // displays the created frame

Console::WriteLine("Press any key to start video sampling...");
//Console::ReadLine();

IMFSample *videoSample = NULL;
DWORD streamIndex, flags;
LONGLONG llTimeStamp;
bool clockStarted = false;
IMFSample *d3dSample = nullptr;
LONGLONG llVideoTimeStamp = 0;
UINT32 uiAttribute = 0;
IMFMediaBuffer* pSrcBuffer = NULL;
IMFMediaBuffer* pDstBuffer = NULL;
IMF2DBuffer* p2DBuffer = NULL;
BYTE* pbBuffer = NULL;
DWORD dwBuffer = 0;

while (true)
{
    CHECK_HR(videoReader->ReadSample(
        MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
        0,                              // Flags.
        &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
        &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
        &llTimeStamp,                   // Receives the time stamp.
        &videoSample                    // Receives the sample or NULL.
    ), "Error reading video sample.");

    if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
    {
        printf("End of stream.\n");
        break;
    }
    if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK)
    {
        printf("Stream tick.\n");
    }

    if (!videoSample)
    {
        printf("Null video sample.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        /*if (!clockStarted)
        {
        clockStarted = true;
        CHECK_HR(pClock->Start(llTimeStamp), "Error starting the presentation clock.\n");
        }*/

        printf("Attempting to write sample to stream sink.\n");

        //CHECK_HR(videoSample->SetSampleTime(llTimeStamp), "Error setting the video sample time.\n");
        //CHECK_HR(videoSample->SetSampleDuration(41000000), "Error setting the video sample duration.\n");

        /*CHECK_HR(CreateD3DSample(_pSwapChain, &d3dSample), "Failed to create 3D sample.\n");
        CHECK_HR(d3dSample->SetSampleTime(llTimeStamp), "Error setting the 3D sample time.\n");*/

        //CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->ProcessSample(videoSample), "Streamsink process sample failed.\n");
        //CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->ProcessSample(d3dSample), "Streamsink process sample failed.\n");

        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetSampleTime(&llVideoTimeStamp), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->SetSampleTime(llVideoTimeStamp), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetSampleDuration(&llVideoTimeStamp), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->SetSampleDuration(llVideoTimeStamp), ".\n");

        CHECK_HR(videoSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pSrcBuffer), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pSrcBuffer->Lock(&pbBuffer, NULL, &dwBuffer), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &pDstBuffer), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pDstBuffer->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&p2DBuffer)), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(p2DBuffer->ContiguousCopyFrom(pbBuffer, dwBuffer), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pSrcBuffer->Unlock(), ".\n");

        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_FrameCorruption, &uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->SetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_FrameCorruption, uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity, &uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->SetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity, uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, &uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->SetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, &uiAttribute), ".\n");
        CHECK_HR(pD3DVideoSample->SetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, uiAttribute), ".\n");

        CHECK_HR(pStreamSink->ProcessSample(pD3DVideoSample), "Streamsink process sample failed.\n");

        Sleep(75);
    }

    SafeRelease(&p2DBuffer);
    SafeRelease(&pDstBuffer);
    SafeRelease(&pSrcBuffer);
    SafeRelease(&videoSample);
}

done:

// Todo : stop clock - shutdown object - release object

SafeRelease(_d3ddev);    // close and release the 3D device
SafeRelease(_d3d);    // close and release Direct3D

printf("finished.\n");
getchar();

return 0;
}

HRESULT CreateD3DSample(
IDirect3DSwapChain9 *pSwapChain,
IMFSample **ppVideoSample
)
{
// Caller holds the object lock.

D3DCOLOR clrBlack = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface = NULL;
IMFSample* pSample = NULL;

// Get the back buffer surface.
HRESULT hr = pSwapChain->GetBackBuffer(
    0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

// Fill it with black.
hr = _d3ddev->ColorFill(pSurface, NULL, clrBlack);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

// Create the sample.
hr = MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface(pSurface, &pSample);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

// Return the pointer to the caller.
*ppVideoSample = pSample;
(*ppVideoSample)->AddRef();

done:
SafeRelease(&pSurface);
SafeRelease(&pSample);
return hr;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void InitializeWindow()
{
WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };

wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

if (RegisterClass(&wc))
{
    _hwnd = CreateWindow(
        CLASS_NAME,
        WINDOW_NAME,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        VIDEO_WIDTH,
        VIDEO_HEIGHT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );

    if (_hwnd)
    {
        ShowWindow(_hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        MSG msg = { 0 };

        while (true)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't spot the edit that added the code until today. And it does get some video displaying for me!

Answer (score 1):

Happened across a post on the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/870ba669-44e5-4813-b1a9-8662b3522ae3/the-enhanced-video-renderer-evr-media-sink-can-be-used-as-a-standalone-component-imfstreamsink?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment) which makes mention of the fact that the EVR requires a D3D surface sample rather than a standard IMFSample. I did suspect the problem might be something like that. I don't know exactly how to supply the D3D sample to the EVR and I have already had a few goes at doing so but at least I now know which direction to follow.

Comment: were you able to solve it?. It may be improper to ask as you tried this years ago, I'm also facing the same problem and struggling to get this application to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ram only spotted this comment yesterday. mofo77's answer above got it working for me. My now working sample program is at https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/tree/master/MFVideoEVR.